# How to access instance variable inside block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql, block

I'm working with gem [graphql-client](https://github.com/github/graphql-client) & want to make it dynamic for different URL and token.

The example given in gem documentation & other places has hard coded URL & token.

I'm trying to access `@shop.token` inside `def headers` block of `GraphQL::Client::HTTP`

```
class Graphql

  def initialize(shop_id)
    @shop = Shop.find_by(shop_id)
  end

  def http
    GraphQL::Client::HTTP.new("http://graphql-swapi.parseapp.com/") do
      def headers(context)
        { 
          "User-Agent": "My Client",
          "Token" : @shop.token
        }
      end
    end
  end

  def client
      schema = GraphQL::Client.load_schema(http{@shop})
      
      @client ||= GraphQL::Client.new(schema: schema, execute: http{@shop}).tap do |client|
        client.allow_dynamic_queries = true
      end
  end

end
```

Rails can provide accessing instance variables inside block by `yield` or `self.instance_eval(&block)`
But can we access **@shop** inside the headers method to make token as dynamic.

graphql-client http class is defined [here](https://github.com/github/graphql-client/blob/master/lib/graphql/client/http.rb)

Comment: How do you actually use the client, in the code? It feels like maybe you could be passing the token as part of the context, i.e. `"Token" : context[:token]`? Similar to how [the `user_id` is forwarded to the context in the README](https://github.com/github/graphql-client#executing-queries)?

Comment: You may try a with lambda `{ "User-Agent": "My Client", "Token" : lambda {@shop.token} }` . It will not work directly though, you'll have to use it with a `.call`

Comment: @TomLord I have updated the code for client, can you please have a look

Comment: OK, and how do you construct a query? Again, just looking at that README, the `context` is passed in to each query. So would it be viable to pass `token: @shop.token` along with each query? Have you, for example, defined a `Graphql#query` method?

Comment: @TomLord Thanks, will try to pass it through context while calling query method

Comment: "Do not use nested method definitions, use lambda instead. Nested method definitions actually produce methods in the same scope (e.g. class) as the outer method. Furthermore, the "nested method" will be redefined every time the method containing its definition is called." https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#no-nested-methods

Comment: @max yes, except that there’s an instance evaluation going on here. Click the link at the top of OP’s question.